# Process incoming files in a directory

Tags: java, file, directory

I want to make a Java program that monitors a directory continuously for a new file,

and if a new file arrives, process it and then delete it.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Check for new files, process them, rinse, and repeat:

```
while (true) {
    File[] files = new File(DIRECTORY_PATH).listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        /* do something with this file */

        //and delete it when finished
        file.delete();
    }

    //Pause for a second before checking again
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

JDK 7 includes the `java.nio.file.WatchService` class that allows you to be notified of filesystem changes when they happen rather than continuously poll. It is currently available in OpenJDK as well:

[JDK 7 features](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/nio/)

[OpenJDK WatchService tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html#concerns)